# osquery on-demand yara scan Error: no such column: pattern

Tags: osquery

I'm trying to run on-demand yara scan in osqueryi using 'pattern' constraints but that column is not there and getting error below. Am i missing something on how to use pattern constraints?

```
select * from yara where pattern="/bin/%sh" and sig_group="sig_group_1";
Error: no such column: pattern
```

Just referencing the osquery yara documentation here that i followed:
https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment/yara/

```
osquery> SELECT * FROM yara WHERE pattern="/bin/%sh" AND sigfile="/Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig";
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+
| path      | matches | count | sig_group | sigfile                 | pattern  |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+
| /bin/bash |         | 0     |           | /Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig | /bin/%sh |
| /bin/csh  |         | 0     |           | /Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig | /bin/%sh |
| /bin/ksh  |         | 0     |           | /Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig | /bin/%sh |
| /bin/sh   |         | 0     |           | /Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig | /bin/%sh |
| /bin/tcsh |         | 0     |           | /Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig | /bin/%sh |
| /bin/zsh  |         | 0     |           | /Users/wxs/sigs/baz.sig | /bin/%sh |
+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------------------+----------+
osquery>
```

And the table schema of yara don't have column 'pattern' either:
https://osquery.io/schema/4.8.0/#yara

Answer (score 0):

Those linked docs appear to be out of date. As you point out, there is no `pattern` column.

It looks like you should be able to use a pattern on `path`. From the [examples](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/blob/master/specs/yara/yara.table#L22) in the source code:

```
select * from yara where path LIKE '/etc/%'
```

(I don't use yara, and can't easily confirm this)